# How to measure the time of dtach

Tags: linux, shell

I have a process I am running via `dtach`. I would like to measure it's time and write it to a file. let's call the process `ls -l`.

I've tried several things I saw around but couldn't make it work.. 
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

`time` command may help you:

```
time dtach -c /tmp/foofoo -Ez ls -l
```

output:

```
...
...
[EOF - dtach terminating]

real    0m0.005s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Comment: but then if I want to undtach(say it;s a long process), it will count time until detached